# Extracting star rating using Selenium

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, xpath

I am trying to extract the star rating from a review using `Selenium`, the html tag is as follows:

```
 <p class="inlineRating starRating"><span class="current-rating" style="width: 80%">
        Current Rating: 4</span></p>
```

using `selenium`,I did this

```
rating = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#ctnStars > div.catRatings.firstEl.clearfix > p.inlineRating.starRating > span')    
rating = rating.text
```

The output which I always get is:

> Current Rating: 0

I have tried the `xpath` method as well, scrapy is facing difficulties to shell the page and I am coding in `python`. Please Help.

page url : http://www.webmd.com/drugs/drugreview-19924-cyclophosphamide+intravenous.aspx?drugid=19924&drugname=cyclophosphamide+intravenous&sortby=3

Comment: from which page are you extracting these values ? please post the url too.

Comment: If you check the source code of the ratings in **Overall User Ratings**, you will see that the Current Rating is 0. If you check the ratings in other sections, the value is good there.

Comment: if xpath, you may try this `substring-after(//span[@class="current-rating" ]/text() ,"Current Rating: ")`

Answer (score 1):

Since there are multiple reviews, the driver.find_element_by_css_selector() call probably returning a different review than you think.  You'll need to first find the reviewer, then you can get the review.  something like should work (if I got that Python loop correct):

```
user_posts = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.userPost')
for each user_post in user_posts
   effectiveness_rating = user_post.find_element_by_css_selector('#ctnStars > div.catRatings.firstEl.clearfix > p.inlineRating.starRating > span')
```

Answer (score 0):

The xpath to find star rating for Effectiveness for a specific Reviewer would be:

```
//p[@class='reviewerInfo' and contains(text(),'Reviewer: Sandy')]/following-sibling::div//div[contains(@class,'catRatings firstEl clearfix')]//span[@class='current-rating']/text()
```

you could do the same for other categories...